# How can we generate Java 8 Optional getters using jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, option-type, jsonschema2pojo

Generating java Pojo classes using gradle plugin jsonschema2pojo but i need to generate java8 optonal getter method

Example.json

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    }
}
```

Generating getter method like below in Example.java:

```
@JsonProperty("foo")
public String getFoo() {
return foo;
}
```

But i need jav 8 Optional type getter method

```
@JsonProperty("foo")
public Optional<String> getFoo() {
return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `useOptionalForGetters` parameter into your plugin config

```
jsonSchema2Pojo {

    useOptionalForGetters true

}
```

I have tested it with `org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:1.0.2`